# Javascript Array elements not writing to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a Javascript function that reads entries from an HTML form into an array. However, when I try to read the array into a display element back on the HTML page, it shows up blank. I debugged and know the elements are getting into the array fine, but they aren't displaying when I use innerhtml on my desired output elements. Any help? Below is my JS code (the changepage function isn't complete)

```js
var attributes = new Array("Name", "Nickname", "Email", "Favorite Movie", "Favorite Book", "Favorite Music", "Paragraph", "Image", "Page Background", "Text Color", 0)

function populateAttributes(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById("myForm");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++){
        if (userInput.elements[i].value == null){
            document.write("All fields must be entered. Please try again.");
            break;
        } else {
        attributes[i] = userInput.elements[i].value;
        }
    }
    changePage();
}

function changePage(){
    document.getElementById("nameOutput").innerHTML = attributes[0];
    document.getElementById("avatar").src = attributes[7];
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = attributes[8];
    document.body.style.color = attributes[9];
    document.body.style.fontSize = attributes[10];
}
```

And here is the HTML code

```html
<form id="myForm" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return populateAttributes()">
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
    <label for="nickname">Nickname:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="nickname" name="nickname"><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
    <label for="movie">Favorite Movie:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="movie" name="movie"><br>
    <label for="book">Favorite Book:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="book" name="book"><br>
    <label for="music">Favorite Type Of Music:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="music" name="music"><br>
    <label for="name">About You:</label><br>
    <textarea id="about" name="about" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
    <label for="avatar">Link To Avatar Image:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="avatar" name="avatar"><br><br>
    <label for="background">Select a background color:</label><br>
    <select id="background" name="background">
        <option value="white">White</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select><br>
    <label for="txtcolor">Select a text color:</label><br>
    <select id="txtcolor" name="txtcolor">
        <option value="white">White</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select><br>
    <label for="txtsize">Enter text size (in pixels):</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="txtsize" name="txtsize"><br><br>
    <input type="submit">               
</form> 
 
<p>Name: <span id="nameOutput" class="result"></span></p>
```

Edit: I may have found the issue. After debugging, it shows that the values are in fact reading into the array. However, as soon as the function ends, it reverts back to a normal page. I'm not sure how to keep the values after the page reloads

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Please provide some HTML code.

Comment: Just added the HTML

Comment: You have to stop the form from submitting, which in this case reloads the page. You already have `onsubmit="return ...` but `populateAttributes()` doesn't return anything that would stop the form from submitting. Add `return false;`

Comment: Possible dupe targets: [How to prevent form from being submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted), [JavaScript code to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission)

Comment: @Andreas that fixed it!